# Create Select Tag from Split String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, dom

How do I split this string:

```
waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse
```

...by `||`?

Then, I'd like to create a select list like this:

```
<select name="options" id="options">
  <option value="waterfowl">waterfowl</option>
  <option value="tvs">tvs</option>
  <option value="guitar">guitar</option>
  <option value="pillow">pillow</option>
  <option value="mouse">mouse</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you show us where you are stuck? all you need to do is to loop through your array and create the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var options = 'waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse';

$( '#someDiv' ).html( '<select name="options" id="options">'
    + options.replace(/(\w+)\|*/g, '<option value="$1">$1</option>')
    + '</select>' );
```

Comment: Theres no reason to use html here :\

Comment: @Raynos - No reason to use jquery here to do something that's trivial in straight JS.  No reason to use DOM nodes that would take significantly more code.

Comment: There's plenty of reason to favour DOM nodes over HTML. The page is a document, not some HTML string that should be hacked.

Comment: ideas like that are just plain wrong, no offense ;)  You should use whatever tools get the job done unless there's something fundamentally wrong with them.  There is nothing fundamentally wrong with `.innerHTML` even though you may not like it.  In more complicated cases, I totally agree that DOM methods are superior, but I ___hate___ arguments that "you should never use that method because [insert personal opinion here]".  Now if you could legitimately say "`innerHTML` is broken in browsers `[x]` in case `[y]`", you'd have an argument.

Comment: It breaks [seperations of concerns to have in-line HTML as strings in javascript](http://raynos.org/blog/15/No-inline-HTML-in-javascript!). That's bad design and bad practice if you ask me.

Comment: So to make your case you link to your own blog as if it's definitive?  :/  Explain to me how inline HTML is any worse than inline DOM creation as far as separation of content goes.  ___they're the same thing___ in that context.  Besides, you just made my argument for me with your _"if you ask me"_ statement -- yours is an _opinion_ that should ___never___ be spouted as "never do this", only "you probably shouldn't do this because..."

Comment: no, I link to my own blog so I don't have to repeat the argument again.

Comment: I guess my main problem is that your ripping massive chunks of the document out, telling the browser to take some serialized DOm representation (html) and build a new dom tree then inject it into the document. That's a very violent way of doing this. When instead you could just manipulate the DOM as a set of live nodes. I can see your point though, this is personal design philosophy rather then what you should and shouldn't do.

Comment: oh, I totally get and agree with the argument that you shouldn't do DOM _creation_ ___at all___ inside of JS in many cases.  HTML should stay in HTML, as should CSS.  But I don't see how `innerHTML` is fundamentally any different in this context than `document.createElement`

Comment: I guess it does come down to a personal preference of mine to prefer DOM creation over html in all cases. that or I can't explain why the DOM is better.

Answer (score 3):

```
// Turns a string in to a combo box based on:
// @d      Delimiter to split the string up by
// @so     Select box attributes (adding name="foo" means passing {name:'foo'})
// Result: jQuery object of the new select element, populated with the items
//         from the string
String.prototype.toSelect = function(d,so){
    so = so || {};

    var s = $('<select/>',so),
        items = this.split(d);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        $('<option/>').val(items[i]).text(items[i]).appendTo(s);
    }
    return s;
}

// an example
// Append the following string to the body of the document
// after it's been converted in to  a <Select> element
$('body').append("waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse".toSelect('||',{
    name: 'select',
    id: 'select'
}));
```

Version with a bit more flexibility (and jQuery abilities): http://jsfiddle.net/j6DjR/

Comment: >_> can we not corrupt the string prototype with junk like this

Comment: I just used the prototype for simplicity, doesn't mean you can't break it off and change it to `function toSelect(string,d,so){`... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var input = 'waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse';
var split = input.split('||');
var select = $('<select name="options" id="options"></select>');
$.each(split, function(index, value) {
  var option = $('<option></option>');
  option.attr('value', value);
  option.text(value);
  select.append(option);
});
$('#idOfContainer').empty().append(select);
```

Comment: I liked this answer because it doesn't use HTML string manipulation and it doesn't needlessly add junk to `String.prototype`, but I had to tweak it to get it to work.  For some reason, `option.text(this)` doesn't work, but `option.text(s)` does.  There's a discrepancy between the types of `s` and `this`, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: Why do you use `.html(select)` instead of `.append(select)`

Comment: @Raynos: The idea is to replace the container's content with the `select`, rather than just adding on to whatever's there.  Looking at the source of `.html`, its last case does: `this.empty().append( value )` .  But I agree: `.empty().append(select)` would be more explicit.

Comment: @JoeyAdams using `.html()` is a hack. you want `.empty().append(...)`

Comment: @JoeyAdams realised why this .attr('value', this) didn't work - javascript will always wrap the 'this' value as an Object, my bad. Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Raynos Just looked into what html does under the covers... code now updated to use .empty().append()!

Answer (score 2):

### Preamble:

I used a `<select>` element with `id` and `name` attributes of
"assorted". "options" is a terrible id/name for a form element.
Read here for more: http://www.fortybelow.ca/hosted/comp-lang-javascript/faq/names/

---

### Code:

No mess, no fuss.

(`commonElements.testing` is the form containing the `<select>` element)

```
var commonElements =
{
    "testing": document.getElementById("testing"),
    "assorted": document.getElementById("assorted")
},
options = "waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse";

function addOptions (optionList)
{
    var i = 0,
    limit = optionList.length,
    parent = commonElements.assorted,
    option;
    for (i;i<limit;i++)
    {
        option = document.createElement(
            "option"
        );
        option.text = optionList[i];
        option.value = optionList[i];
        parent.add(option, null);
    }
}

function createOptions (toSplit)
{
    var optionList = toSplit.split("||");
    addOptions(optionList);
}

createOptions(options);
```

#### Working Link (with full code):

http://jsbin.com/ucajep

Comment: +1 for using the DOM. `HTMLSelectElement::add` and `HTMLOptionElement::text` is where it's at

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple:

1. Split string, using || as separator.
2. Loop over the splitted string.

   1. Create a new `option` element
   2. Set its value and text to the current item
   3. Add the element to containing `select` element

Here's a simple implementation of it (without using jQuery). I use `Array.prototype.forEach` and `element.textContent` (the former being ES5 and latter being non-IE), but it should bring the point across (and they're not hard to shim).

```
function makeSelect( options, separator ) {
    var select = document.createElement( 'select' ),
        optionElem;

    options.split( separator || '||' ).forEach(function( item ) {

        optionElem = document.createElement( 'option' );

        optionElem.value =
            optionElem.textContent =
                item;

        select.appendChild( optionElem );
    });

    return select;
}

var selectElem = makeSelect( 'waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse' );
```

You can then manipulate `selectElem` just like you'd manipulate any other DOM element.

Comment: Use `optionElem.text` instead of `.textContent`

Answer (score -1):

You can split the string into an array, then iterate through the array building an HTML string that you can then append to the DOM:

```
var str = 'waterfowl||tvs||guitar||pillow||mouse',//the string to be split
    arr = str.split('||'),//the split string, each split stored in an index of an array
    out = '';//our output buffer variable

//iterate through each array index
for (var index; index < arr.length; i++) {

    //add this index to the output buffer
    out += '<option value="' + arr[index] + '">' + arr[index] + '</option>';
}

//add the HTML we've built to the DOM, you can also use `.append(<code>)` instead of `.html(<code>)` but if you are using an ID for your select element then you ant to make sure and replace the HTML
$('#container-element').html('<select name="options" id="options">' + out + '</select>');
```

Here's a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/eb5Dj/

Comment: Ew, string concatenation. Hopefully the string doesn't ever contain double quotes... (`foo||"bar"||baz` makes this bomb) Also, you should take advantage of jQuery and it's ability to build DOM elements. (String parsing is not an ideal way of building DOM elements.)

Comment: String concatenation is a perfectly valid way to build elements and will be a couple orders of magnitude faster than using jQuery to assign individual attributes to new nodes.  Also, jQuery uses `.innerHTML` all the time to actually create nodes.  Granted in this case I doubt speed matters enough, but I also doubt that there would be quotes in a select box (possible, but very rare) and it's easy to handle if there were.

Comment: @BradChristie My method is close to twice as fast (of course this depends on the browser); it does however have the issue with double-quotes. Here is a jsperf with our two codes: http://jsperf.com/toselect-vs-string-con

Comment: Just an FYI, seeing 4x faster in Chrome 16

Comment: @cwolves lies. innerHTML is not faster then the DOM. It is faster then jQuery but the answer is use the DOM not innerHTML

Comment: So are these down-votes for the double-quotes? I don't see why else there would be a necessity to down-vote.

Comment: @Jasper there are downvotes for using [inline HTML which is always wrong](http://raynos.org/blog/15/No-inline-HTML-in-javascript!)

Comment: I personally voted for the greatest sin that is `for..in` for arrays plus using an undeclared variable

Comment: @Raynos For my benefit, since it creates less overhead, why not use inline HTML in JavaScript?

Comment: @Jasper because it encourages hacking, spaghetti and generally low quality code. If you want to do low quality code, that's your choice, don't recommend that to other people

Comment: @Raynos I'd like to know more and I'm not finding much on the subject. Could you suggest a search or any info on this? More specifically how does it encourage "hacking, spaghetti..."? Thanks.

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for the response. I see that not declaring the `index` var creates an unnecessary global. I'd like to learn more, what else is explicitly wrong with using `for (var i in a) {...}`?

Comment: @Jasper the same way string concatenating SQL queries encourages hacking and spaghetti code. Talk to any server developer and they'll shoot your for string concatenating SQL. Same applies to HTML. The reason you can't find any is because most people still think it's "ok". It's actually controversial for me to say it's bad.

Comment: @Jasper `for .. in` loop over arrays are evil. Use `for (i = 0;i<len;i++)` mainly for speed reasons

Comment: @Jasper, It's much slower than `for` loop, the ordering of indexes is not guaranteed, it's simply unspecified, it loops through enumerable array prototype properties and is generally useless when you need to do array index arithmetic inside the loop.

Comment: @Raynos Thanks for the response. OK, so if the string being split is supplied by a user it could introduce malicious code (`" onClick="alert('gotcha');`). If the source of the string is controlled (say comes from a database with no user interaction) then would this still be an issue?

Comment: @Raynos I don't know why I hadn't done this before ( http://jsperf.com/for-in-tests ) but yeah its must faster to do `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {...}`. **Thanks for everyone's input.**

Comment: @Jasper, you get 80x faster when you cache arr.length, without caching it seems it's just 20x

Comment: @Esailija That's awesome how much faster it is, I'm actually kinda excited to go fix some of the code I've *messed up* in the last few months. **Again, thanks for all the advice.**

Comment: @Jasper I just have a high dislike of string concatenation html. There's no need for it when you can use the DOM. It's just mindless overhead to use the HTML parser. And it compeltely breaks seperations of concerns. html has no business being in string literals. that's almost as bad as `document.write(entirePage)`

Comment: @raynos - sorry, didn't see all these messages :)  Please explain, then, why every library under the sun optimizes to `.innerHTML`.  Explain benchmarks that prove `innerHTML` is ___significantly___ quicker in ALL older browsers and marginally quicker in newer ones.  By 'significantly', I mean 10x or more in some browsers, 100x faster (literally) in IE6.  If you don't believe me: http://bit.ly/tJauNO

Comment: @cwolves personal innerHTML vs DOM benchmarks say there is no difference in modern browsers. Some prefer DOM in some cases, some prefer innerHTML in some cases. I agree inner HTML is faster in legacy browsers but meh. I'll use hacks for speed if I need to, until then I use the DOM.